# Scrapy does not print the sites crawling on

Tags: scrapy, css-selectors

```html
    <a href="/what-to-watch/fan-favorites/?ref_=hm_fanfav_sm" class="ipc-title ipc-title--
    subsection-title ipc-title--baseAlt ipc-title--on-textPrimary ipc-title-link-wrapper" 
    tabindex="0"><h3 class="ipc-title__text">Fan favorites<svg width="24" height="24" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="ipc-icon ipc-icon--chevron-right-inline ipc-
    icon--inline ipc-title-link-chevron" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="currentColor" 
    role="presentation"><path d="M5.622.631A2.153 2.153 0 0 0 5 2.147c0 .568.224 1.113.622 
    1.515l8.249 8.34-8.25 8.34a2.16 2.16 0 0 0-.548 2.07c.196.74.768 1.317 1.499 1.515a2.104 
    2.104 0 0 0 2.048-.555l9.758-9.866a2.153 2.153 0 0 0 0-3.03L8.62.61C7.812-.207 6.45-.207 
    5.622.63z"></path></svg></h3><div class="ipc-title__description">This week's top TV and 
    movies</div></a>
```

and

```html
        <a class="ipc-poster-card__title ipc-poster-card__title--clamp-2
    ipc-poster-card__title--clickable" aria-label="View title page for 
    Shang-Chi and the Legend of the Ten Rings" href="/title/tt9376612/?
    ref_=watch_fanfav_tt_t_2"><span data-testid="title">Shang-Chi and the 
    Legend of the Ten Rings</span></a>
```

Are the HTML structures of the sites I want my spider to crawl with the code:

```py
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
    
    class imdb_favorites(scrapy.Spider):
        
        name = "imdB Favorites"
        
        def start_requests(self):
            url = "https://www.imdb.com"
            yield scrapy.Request(url = url,
                                callback = self.parse_front)
            
        def parse_front(self, response):
            # Get the link of 'What to watch section'
            fan_favorites = response.css('div.fan-picks>a::attr(href)')
            link_to_follow =  fan_favorites.extract()
            for i in link_to_follow:
                url2 = url + i 
                print(url2)
                yield response.follow(url = url2,
                                      callback = self.parse_2)
            
        def parse_2(self, response):
            # Gets the links of the movies in what to watch section.
            what_to_watch = response.css('a.ipc-poster-card__title::attr(href)').extract()
            for a in what_to_watch:
                url3 = "https://www.imdb.com" + a
                print(url3)
                yield response.follow(url = url3,
                                     callback = parse_3)
                
    process= CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(imdb_favorites)
    process.start()
```

The problem is that print() functions do not work in for loops so I cannot see if my code crawls properly or not so I cannot teach myself furthermore. Thanks your interest.

Comment: The print function should work in for loops. Can you please check with print() if `link_to_follow` and `what_to_watch` have values? Also, you might have an error in parse_front, you use `url2 = url + i` while url is not assigned in parse_front but in start_requests. Did you maybe want to use `self.url` in start_requests & parse_front?

Comment: @PatrickKlein I have followed all the instructions you have provided and parse_front works nice and clean (at least for the print function). However parse_2 part prints neither what_to_watch nor url3 maybe I have made a mistake in selector while navigating the crawler to parse_2

Answer (score 0):

1. Print should work in a loop; this indicates you never actually enter the loop. Print/log (see below) information about the iterable before entering the loop to see if it is in fact an iterable. Printing `print(len(what_to_watch))` or `print(len(link_to_follow))` right before each loop should return an integer if it is an iterable. You can then log individual aspects of the iterable such as the first element. Note: this is a makeshift way to debug, and I would recommend using [scrapy shell](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html) or running the spider in debug mode and putting breakpoints in your loops to see if they ever get hit. See [scrapy documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/debug.html) for information about debugging.
2. If printing really is the problem, try logging instead of printing. it's possible you have some setting configured such that it is not handling standard-output the way you are expecting. Read more about scrapy logging [here](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html). You can bulk replace your `print()` with `logging.info()`.